# Psycopg2 formatting error when using SQL module

Tags: postgresql, syntax, psycopg2

I imagine this will be an easy one for somebody but I can't figure it out...

I am developing a SQL query dynamically following the instructions [here](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html). After creating postgresql connection and cursor object, I use the psycopg2 sql module to create a query with parameters as such:

```
query = sql.SQL("SELECT * FROM {t_name} WHERE {col} in %s;".format(
    t_name=sql.Identifier(table_name),
    col=sql.Identifier(fips_col)))
```

This works fine (as far as I know) with this result:

```
SQL("SELECT * FROM Identifier('cb_tracts') WHERE Identifier('st_cnty_fips') in %s;")
```

I then try to execute with an argument (or list of arguments):

```
cursor.execute(query, ('06037',))
```

or

```
cursor.execute(query, (['06037'],))
```

But I am getting this error:

```
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "'06073'"
LINE 1: ...er('cb_tracts') WHERE Identifier('st_cnty_fips') in '06073';
```

and this error, respectively:

```
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "ARRAY"
LINE 1: ...('cb_tracts') WHERE Identifier('st_cnty_fips') in ARRAY['060...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL `IN (...)` is actually a syntactic construction rather than a function or anything like that. Which means that it takes a comma-separated list of literal values rather than a single value that is a list (if you can see the difference).

This means the value-binding that almost every database driver uses can't work with `IN (...)` even though everybody thinks it should.

The way you would express a list as a single value in PostgreSQL is an array. The way to check for membership of an array is with

```
... my_column = ANY(%s)
```

Comment: Thanks! Hmmm...I thought the purpose of psycopg2 was to format queries correctly? So, what do I need to do to format this query correctly?

Comment: What I said. Express it as an array and use ANY

Comment: See here [list/array](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#adapt-list) for the docs confirmation of what @RichardHuxton is telling you. Also from Postgres docs [Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions.html)  for the different uses of `IN`; [Subquery](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions.html) and [Row/Array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-comparisons.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISONS-IN-SCALAR).

Comment: If you want to work with just one value then `...Identifier('st_cnty_fips') = '06073'`.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I misunderstood. Thanks for your help!